# extracting keyframes from damaged video file

Tags: video, file-formats

if I have a video file that is in .mov format, but the header has been overwritten, is there a way to scan the file to find the keyframes and somehow extract  them?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the file through [recover_mp4_to_h264](http://www.videohelp.com/software/recover-mp4-to-h264), assuming video codec is H.264. You will need to supply a good reference file i.e. with valid header, of the same type as the damaged one.